# While-loop after SQL query won't work PHP

Tags: php

```
$mysqli_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".$snt_stone." ");   
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query)){

        $DatabaseID = $result['DatabaseID'];
        $ItemName = $result['ItemName'];
        $ItemStatus = $result['ItemStatus'];
        $ItemCategory = $result['ItemCategory'];

        }
```

I have multiple things in my database but for some reason my while loop only loops once. How can I make it loop through every item/row once?

Comment: Your loop doesn't do anything. It just assigns some variables, which will be overwritten in the next iteration.

Comment: @Erik I didnt provide the entire code, but it does a lot more below it. And i believe the error is in the query but might be wrong

Comment: I assume running the same query (print it out) returns more than 1 row if you execute the SQL directly in your DB?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't understand how while loop works.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query)){
$DatabaseID = $result['DatabaseID'];
}
```

This loop gives value of `$result['DatabaseID'];` to variable `$DatabaseID`. When you loop second time `$DatabaseID` has its value changed again.

Thus what you basically do is run through the results of your `SELECT` query and every time give the values you fetched to the group of particular variables overwritting them each time you go through the loop.

You can check your logic error by running this:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query)){

   echo $result['DatabaseID'];
   echo $result['ItemName'];
   echo $result['ItemStatus'];
   echo $result['ItemCategory'];

   $DatabaseID = $result['DatabaseID'];
   $ItemName = $result['ItemName'];
   $ItemStatus = $result['ItemStatus'];
   $ItemCategory = $result['ItemCategory'];

    }
```

You will see that echo gives all the results from select but since you keep on overwritting the variable only the last value is saved.

EDIT

I think that the simplest solution to your problem would be save the values you need as an array and then work with the array. The simplest way to do it would be:

```
$mysqli_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".$snt_stone." ");   
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query)){

        $DatabaseID[] = $result['DatabaseID'];
        $ItemName[] = $result['ItemName'];
        $ItemStatus[] = $result['ItemStatus'];
        $ItemCategory[] = $result['ItemCategory'];

        }
```

Then you can run `print_r($DatabaseID)` to print the array content.

Such constructed array would be rather unhandy to use, check php's manual on arrays and create one that would best fill your needs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Of course it also depends on what you want to do with those values later on in your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $mysqli_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".$snt_stone." ");   
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query)){

       echo  $result['DatabaseID'];
       echo $result['ItemName'];
       echo $result['ItemStatus'];
       echo $result['ItemCategory'];

    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.